# Коллектор Traffic flow для Микротик

Tags: delphi

Доброго времени суток! 
Имееться машина с ОС микротик. На которой настроен *Сенсор* Traffic flow который отправляет данные на IP 10.10.10.10 port 9996 (я точно не знаю но думаю что используеться UDP протокол). Я думаю не мало людей задавалось вопросом построить свой *коллектор* который будет отображать данные в том виде, в каком мы хотим их видеть!
Вот попробовал написать что-то свое но это не дало результатов :(. Использовал компонент IdUDPServer1. хотелось бы просто выводить в *Мемо* то что отправляет *микротик*

```
uses idSocketHandle

procedure TForm1.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
AData: TBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
s: String;
i:Integer;
begin
  s := '';
  try
  i := 0;
  while (AData[i] <> 0) do
    begin
      s := s + chr(AData[i]);
      i := i + 1;
    end;
    finally
    Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  end;
end;
```

При запуске я вижу что курсор бежит в низ в поле *Мемо* но данные не выводяться  :(.
Может я использую не тот компонент или уже существуют другие компоненты для этого дела?

Comment: Поставьте монитор трафика на 10.10.10.10 (например Wireshark) и увидите получает что-то и в каком виде, на каком протоколе...

Компонент, скорее всего не тот, у вас же не сервер, а клиент на машине 10.10.10.10 должен быть

Answer (score 1):

Компонент тот используется, IdUDPServer... Компоненты Server и Client из серии Indy это не сервер и клиент в обычном представлении: тут клиент только отправляет данные, а сервер только принимает.
Если курсор бежит вниз - значит какие-то данные принимаются. Скорей всего, Memo просто не может их отобразить (непечатные символы). Советую вам сохранять в данные файл, и потом просто открывать любым HEX-редактором - тогда будет точно известно, что было принято.
А вместо команды Memo1.Lines.Add(s) лучше использовать Memo1.Text:=Memo1.Text+s, тогда не будет лишних символов перевода строки.